# GUI Shop in mcpc

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a GUI shop in minecraft PC with commands on this website http://www.mctoolbox.me/gui/. I don't know how to use it and I would like an example of how to use this using scoreboard currency with buying and selling please I have tried with buttons but this seems a lot easier.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score -1):

On the Minecraft wiki there is a section just for [scoreboard setup](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard), you should check it out. It shows eveything you need to know and how they work.